# Error: Reducer "auth" returned undefined when handling "@@INIT" action. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

Can't figure out what I'm going wrong in this. Just trying to setup the basic ducks and saga for my project practice.

[image: Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this]

Ducks/auth.js

```
    const action = name => `/auth/${name}`;

export const FETCH = action('FETCH');

export const fetchUser = (user) => ({ type: FETCH, user });

const auth = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return console.log('Hello World');
  }
};

export default auth;
```

Sagas/auth.js

```
import {
  fork,
  takeLatest,
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as actions from 'ducks/auth';

export function* fetchUser() {
  yield console.log('Hello World');
}

export function* watchFetchUser() {
  yield takeLatest(actions.FETCH, fetchUser);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(watchFetchUser)
  ];
}
```

Can anyone resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the state in the default case:

```
const auth = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      console.log('Hello World')
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Every time I build a new React project I do the same mistake, over and over and over :-D

Comment: lol. Try to use redux toolkit. They are covering large parts of the boilerplate.